# How to play video in a new tab?

Tags: html, video, attributes

I am a beginner in web development. I have a video file in my web page.

I want to play that video in a new tab.

I gave the target="_blank" attribute into my video tag but it's still not working.

Is there is any other way to play videos in a new tab?

Please help me!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Do you try this way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Click the Link to Play the Object</h2>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/intro.swf" target="_blank">Play a video file</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

Or you can create a blank page with following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    
    <video width="90%" height="90%" controls>
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

And then link to that page:

```
<a href="video_page" target_="blank">See the video</a>
```

Comment: i don't see a solution for this.. wait for more responses or create a blank page with the video and link to that page with target_"blank"