# Need to play video in new tab when I click on the video

Tags: javascript, html

I have html page in which there are set of videos.

Code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <title> TEST </title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <h1>Video testing</h1> 
    <a href="#" id ="play-fullscreen" target="_blank" > 
    <video id="test" width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video> 
    </a> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

When I click on the video it plays in current page. Instead I want that particular video to open in new tab in full screen. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: This opens video in new tab. I want to play that video as soon as it opens and it has to open in full screen. Should I handle that in Java Script function?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Here's a similar question.
[Auto-play an HTML5 video on Dom Load using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842308/auto-play-an-html5-video-on-dom-load-using-jquery)

I don't think this can be done without JS.

This has already being answered:
[How to play video in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674557/how-to-play-video-in-a-new-tab)

If this doesn't work then I would advice you to share your code.

Comment: <html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>
  TEST
</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Video testing</h1>
  <a href="#" id ="play-fullscreen" target="_blank" >
  <video id="test" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  </a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This opens video in new tab. I want to play that video as soon as it opens and it has to open in full screen. How should I handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a full screen video in a new tab, full screen API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

The closest thing you can do is: with CSS, in the new tab with the video set the width and height to 100% of the body.

To autoplay the video the page loads you can do something like this:

```
window.onload = playVideo();

function playVideo() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("test");
    elem.play();
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7Lbhm2va/